# get the full path with statement in twig ( sonatamediabundle)

Tags: twig, sonata-media-bundle

How do I get the fullpath for sonatamediabundle??

I can get the full path normally

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost() ~ path('path_name') }}
```

howevere sonatamediabundle is like this

```
{%  path  pic.getMedia, 'big' %}
```

Is it possible to get the fullpath with the statement???

Comment: On this page there is an example: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/security.html. 

path('sonata_media_download', {'id': media|sonata_urlsafeid })

Can you change that to your needs?